# How to add new field to existed content type

Tags: content-type, feature-receiver, choice-field

I need to add new choice field to existed content type. I'd like to do it in feature activate segment. I understand, I need to get content type by ID or name, then create new choice field with my options, default value and choice type and at last add field to content type. I googled whole day but I don't understand how to realize it.

Show me please by example how to resolve my task.

Answer (score 0):

Create the site column as a separate action from the content type, and then use a "FieldLinkCreationInformation" object to add the site column to the content type. See this page on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/create-sharepoint-content-types-by-using-csom) for a code sample, or google "FieldlinkCreationInformation" for more examples. Or, following is an incomplete PowerShell snippet with the important bits:

```
#load the existing site columns
$context.Load($web.Fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#get a reference to the site column that needs to be added to a content type
$mySiteColumn= $web.Fields.GetByTitle($siteColumnName)
$context.Load($mySiteColumn)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#Get the FieldLink, and add it to the content type 
$mySiteColumnLinkInfo = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLinkCreationInformation
$mySiteColumnLinkInfo.Field=$mySiteColumn
$varthrowaway = $myContentType.FieldLinks.Add($mySiteColumnLinkInfo)

$myContentType.Update($true)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: CSOM is not in my case. And didn't prefer use Powershell for such actions: I think all updates should be centralized store in wsp package for repeated use.

Comment: WSP is on the way out. But if you want server-side, it's a similar procedure, in that the site column is created separately from the content type, and then added via fieldlinks. An example is here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-content-type-using-object-model95/